# Calculating "Trimmed" Weighted Average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, weighted-average

Anyone have any ideas on how to create a formula that will calculated a "trimmed" weighted average?

For example: I have 10 different numbers with their own weights. How do I go about creating a formula that calculates a weighted average of only the 8 middle numbers (highest and lowest value removed).

Thanks in advance for everyone's input - and happy holidays.

**Example**: 
Jen: $5 with a weight of 20%
Harrison: $6 with a weight of 25%
Ford: $1 with a weight of 30%
Bill: $10 with a weight of 25%

Expected output = **I would want the Weighted average of Jen & Harrison** since Ford and Bill have the highest/lowest value.

Comment: Please mock come data and expected output.  Then [edit] your post to include that mock up.

Comment: Do you calculate "middle" based on weights or just the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A1:A4>MIN(A1:A4))*(A1:A4<MAX(A1:A4)),A1:A4*B1:B4))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]